# read data content in TableRow

Tags: android, tablerow

I have a TableRow that is loaded dynamically. It contains multiple EditTexts and CheckBoxes. How do I get the user input from these EditTexts and CheckBoxes?

This my Code

public void cargarProductos(SQLiteDatabase db){
            TableLayout tabla = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.Detalle);

```
        Cursor cProd = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM vstEncProductos WHERE IdCliente="+idCliente+" AND Idcategoria="+IdCategoria, null);
        int ValorChk = 0;


        if (cProd.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                 TableRow row = new TableRow(this);

                 row.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
                 row.setId(cProd.getInt(0));

                 ImageButton btnBarCode = new ImageButton(this);
                 btnBarCode.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.barcodereader48);
                 btnBarCode.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                     public void onClick(View v) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
                            intent.setPackage("com.google.zxing.client.android");
                            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

                     };

                    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
                        if (requestCode == 0) {
                            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                                String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
                            String format = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");
                            showDialog(R.string.result_succeeded, "Format: " + format + "\nContents: " + contents);

                            // Handle successful scan
                            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                                // Handle cancel
                            }
                        }
                        }

                 }); 

                 row.addView(btnBarCode, new TableRow.LayoutParams(0));

                 TextView txtProducto = new TextView(this);
                 txtProducto.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
                 txtProducto.setText(cProd.getString(1));
                 txtProducto.setWidth(230);
                 row.addView(txtProducto, new TableRow.LayoutParams(1));

                 EditText txtPrecio = new EditText(this);
                 txtPrecio.setWidth(130);
                 txtPrecio.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
                 row.addView(txtPrecio, new TableRow.LayoutParams(2));





                 TextView txtPrecioAnt = new TextView(this);
                 txtPrecioAnt.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
                 txtPrecioAnt.setText(cProd.getString(7));
                 txtPrecioAnt.setWidth(115);
                 txtPrecioAnt.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
                 row.addView(txtPrecioAnt, new TableRow.LayoutParams(3));

                 CheckBox chkPresencia = new CheckBox(this);
                 ValorChk=cProd.getInt(4);
                 chkPresencia.setChecked(ValorChk==-1);
                 chkPresencia.setWidth(50);
                 row.addView(chkPresencia, new TableRow.LayoutParams(4));

                 CheckBox chkPrecioPromo = new CheckBox(this);
                 ValorChk=cProd.getInt(4);
                 chkPrecioPromo.setChecked(ValorChk==-1);
                 chkPrecioPromo.setWidth(50);
                 row.addView(chkPrecioPromo, new TableRow.LayoutParams(4));

                 CheckBox chkAlerta = new CheckBox(this);
                 ValorChk=cProd.getInt(4);
                 chkAlerta.setChecked(ValorChk==-1);
                 chkAlerta.setWidth(50);
                 row.addView(chkAlerta, new TableRow.LayoutParams(4));                 

                 tabla.addView(row, new TableLayout.LayoutParams());



            } while (cProd.moveToNext());  
        }

        cProd.close();
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! If you a particular answer is helpful, please up vote it. If a particular answer is correct, please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using some sort of adapter class to load the data into your table. When you create a view, simply assign an [OnClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html) to the checkboxes and a [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) to the EditTexts. Use the callbacks from these classes to do what ever it is you want with the users input. Am I understanding your question correctly?

Comment: Thank you very much, by the TableRow through a cursor, so I do not understand is I have to do to read the data that users enter in order to update my table in the database.

Do not like walking the TableRow and remove the EditText control data and CheckBox

Comment: In the callBacks for OnClickListener and TextWatcher, you should make calls to your database with the updated user information.

Comment: But here is a survey should yolk is much information and at the end that I store all data. to be more explicit I have a 3-TAB TABHOST and in each there is a TableLayout with "N" type TableRow EditText containing and CheckBox controls

I need to read all rows and columns and get data from controls

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't seem to understand what you're asking.

Comment: My question is!
How do I get the data entered by the user in the controls (EditText) that are contained inside a TableRow, which has "N" Rows.

Answer (score 0):

when you are creating new tablerows you can save each file in a multi vector of, for example, strings. Then you only must get size of each vector inside theparent vector. My example with your cody modified:

```
             Vector<Vector<String>> result = new Vector<Vector<String>>();
              Vector<String> vecAux = new Vector<String>();

             TextView txtProducto = new TextView(this);
             txtProducto.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
             txtProducto.setText(cProd.getString(1));
             txtProducto.setWidth(230);
             row.addView(txtProducto, new TableRow.LayoutParams(1));
             vecAux.add(cProd.getString(1));

             EditText txtPrecio = new EditText(this);
             txtPrecio.setWidth(130);
             txtPrecio.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
             row.addView(txtPrecio, new TableRow.LayoutParams(2));


             TextView txtPrecioAnt = new TextView(this);
             txtPrecioAnt.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
             txtPrecioAnt.setText(cProd.getString(7));
             txtPrecioAnt.setWidth(115);
             txtPrecioAnt.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
             row.addView(txtPrecioAnt, new TableRow.LayoutParams(3));
             vecAux.add(cProd.getString(7));

             CheckBox chkPresencia = new CheckBox(this);
             ValorChk=cProd.getInt(4);
             chkPresencia.setChecked(ValorChk==-1);
             chkPresencia.setWidth(50);
             row.addView(chkPresencia, new TableRow.LayoutParams(4));


             CheckBox chkPrecioPromo = new CheckBox(this);
             ValorChk=cProd.getInt(4);
             chkPrecioPromo.setChecked(ValorChk==-1);
             chkPrecioPromo.setWidth(50);
             row.addView(chkPrecioPromo, new TableRow.LayoutParams(4));

             CheckBox chkAlerta = new CheckBox(this);
             ValorChk=cProd.getInt(4);
             chkAlerta.setChecked(ValorChk==-1);
             chkAlerta.setWidth(50);
             row.addView(chkAlerta, new TableRow.LayoutParams(4));                 

             tabla.addView(row, new TableLayout.LayoutParams());
```

### result.add(vecAux);

And get results looking for all position of the vector:

---

```
      String texto = "";

      for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < result.elementAt(i).size(); j++) {
       texto += result.elementAt(i).elementAt(j) + "\t";
        }
      }
```

---

For get if checkbox is checked or not you can get it by ID (findViewById).
I hope help you, bye bye ;-)